# Using XTS algorithm within Botan library for encryption/decryption

Tags: visual-studio-2010, botan

The Botan library (botan.randombit.net/) has a number of algorithms for encryption/decryption. I am interested in using the XTS algorithm for encryption/decryption that is available within Botan. However, there is no example provided for XTS usage in the downloaded Botan library. I need to know the XTS algorithm for encryption/decryption from within Botan. I have been able to compile the Botan library on Windows using MSVC. I am also able to build a sample application that links with this library and use the `LibraryInitializer` function. From this point onwards, I am at loss.

Regards, Saif

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need to get started with Botan, regardless of what algorithm you're using:

http://botan.randombit.net/filters.html

I'll just put this here...

http://botan.randombit.net/pbkdf.html